# How to receive list type data sent from Swagger in my C# .NET Core API?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, swagger

I'm sending Data from Swagger to my API but Not Reciving any List type data in Api; however i'm reciving other data which i'm sending along.

[Image of sending Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLh2d.png)

[Image of what i'm reciveing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VZnt.png)

the code for Controller is :

```
    [HttpPost("CreateDocument")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromForm]CreateDocumentCommand Document)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(new CreateDocumentCommand {Data = Document.Data});
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

my model is:

```
    [Required]
    public string? ContentType { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public long? FileDataSize { get; set; }
    public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public byte[]? FileData { get; set; }
    public IFormFile? Document { get; set; }
    public bool? IsNewVersion { get; set; }
    public Guid? VersionId { get; set; }
    public string? EmailReference { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Attachment>? Attachments { get; set; }
    public bool IsClone { get; set; } = false;
    public string? filePath { get; set; }
    public List<NewDocumentUser>? DocumentUsers { get; set; }

}
public class Attachment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public long? FileDataSize { get; set; }
    public byte[]? FileData { get; set; }
}
public class NewDocumentUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

How to recieve all the informantion i'm sending.

Comment: Please format the question. Show the code of your C# controller. Do you have `FromBody` or `FromForm`, show a clearer image or code of how you pass the data into swagger.

Comment: It seems you are passing the data wrong from Swagger. In the image it states that is an array. Try `[ { "userName": "string", "email": "string" } ]` to pass it as an array. If it doesn't work, include what is the model `CreateDocumentCommand` and the whole Swagger endpoint,

Comment: I'm still not getting any value even after using this [ { "userName": "string", "email": "string" } ]

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Complex types are usually sent using FromBody, and simple types can be sent using form-data. You are trying to send complex type (list of users) using form-data, which causes binding issues.

To make your life a bit easier I would recommend using FromBody, then you will be sending a json Object to your endpoint.

```
[HttpPost("CreateDocument")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody]CreateDocumentCommand Document)
{
    var response = await _mediator.Send(new CreateDocumentCommand {Data = Document.Data});
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Another option would be to take in string from the API. You will then convert it back to an object in your code.

```
public string? DocumentUsers { get; set; }


public List<DocumentUser> GetDocumentUsers() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyUser>>(MyUsers);
```

You can then call the GetDocumentUsers() method (name it whatever you want) which will convert the jsonString to the DocumentUsersObject. You can add exception handling and whatever else.

Remember, this approach is a workaround for the limitations of form-data in ASP.NET Core, and it might not be the best solution if you are working with large amounts of data because of the overhead of serializing and deserializing JSON. If possible, you should consider changing your API to receive a JSON object in the request body, which is more flexible and efficient for handling complex objects.

Comment: Thank you!! the issue is solved now by sending Data through [FromBody}